# codeigniter mysql queries don't work

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I know this isn't good practice to have the queries within a controller, but for some reason they do not work within this controller class. I'm not too experienced with codeigniter, so any help is appreciated, as I have no idea on how else to set this up to work properly. I have an ajax script that gets the information.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

class Phonecall extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {

        /*$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','MYDB');
        if (!$con) {
            die ('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }*/
        //$operatorId = $_SESSION['Oper']['OperatorID']; //I also cannot figure out how to get $_SESSION information either
        //$sql = "SELECT phone_number FROM incoming_calls WHERE OperatorID='${operatorId}'";
        //$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT phone_number FROM MYDB.incoming_calls");// WHERE OperatorID='${operatorId}'");

        while ($row = $query->row_array()) {
            $number = $row['phone_number'];
        }

        /*$sql = "SELECT Username, UserID, Name
            FROM tblUsers 
            WHERE PhoneHome='999-999-9999' OR PhoneCell='999-999-9999' OR PhoneWork='999-999-9999'";
        */

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT Username, UserID, Name
            FROM MYDB.tblUsers 
            WHERE PhoneHome='999-999-9999' OR PhoneCell='999-999-9999' OR PhoneWork='999-999-9999'");

        while ($row = $query->row_array()) {
            $userArray[] = array("name" => $row['Name'], "username" => $row['Username'], "user_id" => $row['UserID']);
        }

        if (!empty($userArray)) {
            echo json_encode($userArray);
        }

        if (isset($_POST["drop"])) {
            $query = $this->db->query("DELETE FROM MYDB.incoming_calls 
                WHERE phone_number = $number
                LIMIT 1");
            if (!$result) {
                die ('Could not drop row: ');
            }
        }

        $this->db->close();
    }
}

?>
```

Here is my JS:

```
    var user = new Array();
    var user_id = new Array();
    var name = new Array();

    $.get(baseURL + 'phonecall/index', function(data) {//where baseURL is defined
        var loginInfo = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        for (var i = 0; i < loginInfo.length; ++i) {
            name[i] = loginInfo[i].name;
            user[i] = loginInfo[i].username;
            user_id[i] = loginInfo[i].user_id;
        }
    }
```

I do not know much about frameworks and I'm trying to learn, I also do not know how to make this file access the $_SESSION data. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: These queries do return data when they're ran by the way.

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? are you getting an error? 
As to the session data, I advise you to read the manual : 
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: The error I'm getting is a server 500 error in the console when the ajax script tries to run. If I run this on my local machine, and change the code up a bit for mysqli queries everything works perfectly. It doesn't give me no other information, other than the 500 server error.

Comment: did you change in the database.php file the engine to mysql(if you're not using mysqli)?

Comment: Use MVC pattern that codeigniter provided to you. Put **models** (for yours sql queries) and **session** (to save it, and access them correctly) libs. And then you will know where errors come from.

Comment: Look in your server logs for the *reason* for the 500 error.

Comment: This question's title is not great.

Answer (score 0):

Always use model for DB queries.

For first query use the following code:

```
$this->db->select("phone_number");
$this->db->from("incoming_calls");
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

For the secound query use this:

```
$this->db->select("Username, UserID, Name");
$this->db->from("tblUsers");
$this->db->where("PhoneHome,'999-999-9999'");
$this->db->where("PhoneCell,'999-999-9999'");
$this->db->where("PhoneWork,'999-999-9999'");
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

Be sure to make 2 different functions for the queries in model.

Then at your controller side use the following code:

```
$data['first_record'] = $this->your_modal_name->your_first_function_name();
$data['secound_record'] = $this->your_modal_name->your_second_function_name();
```

Then run this data in `foreach`, and it will give you the record, which you want.